# How to save SQLite table data on my android device so they appear after the application has restarted?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, onpause

Basically, I want to understand what to implement in order to save the data a user inputs to an SQLite database. Right now I have a main activity that allows you to switch to Second.java. The second activity is where the user can input data to the "gradest" table. If I switch back to MainActivity.java and then go back to SecondActivity.java, the data the user inputted is not displayed. The table appears to be empty again.

It is my understanding that you do not use SharedPreferences for this sort of activity. Could someone point me in the right direction?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void launchGPA(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(
            MainActivity.this,
            Third.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void launchCourses(View view){
    Intent j = new Intent(
            MainActivity.this,
            Second.class);
    startActivity(j);
}
```

}

second.java

```
public class Second extends Activity {
    private TableLayout t1;
    private Grade_Calc  calculator;
    //private count = 0;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        //dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //System.out.println("HURRAY");

        t1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTable);
    }
    public void validate(View v){
        //count+= 1;
        int child_count = t1.getChildCount();
        //System.out.println("child::" + child_count);
        //check to see if dbHelper is null
        Calc_db db = new Calc_db(this);
        db.open();

        //SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //.open()
        //2 children per row
        double[] grades = new double[(child_count*2)];
        for (int i=0; i<child_count; i++){
            TableRow row = (TableRow)t1.getChildAt(i);
            System.out.println("child" + row.getChildCount());
            for (int j=0; j<row.getChildCount();j++){
                EditText text = (EditText)row.getChildAt(j);
                grades[i+j] = isNumValid(text);
            System.out.println("getting text from EditTexts");
            Entry e1 = new Entry (grades[i], grades[i+1]);
            db.addEntry(e1);            
            }
        }
        db.close();
        /*
        //testing purposes
        for (int k=0; k<(child_count*2)-2; k++){
            System.out.println("grade:"+ grades[k]);
        }
        */
        calculator = new Grade_Calc(grades, goal);
        double avg = calculator.getAvgGrade();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        //System.out.println("avgerage"+avg);
        String sAvg=String.valueOf(df.format(avg));
        EditText editTextGrade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextGrade);
        editTextGrade.setText(sAvg);


        //double NeedToAcheive = calculator.getGoalGrade();

    }
    /*
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //Log.e("Inside of onrestoreInstanceState", e.toString());  
    }
    */


    private double isNumValid(EditText text){
        double num = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
        if (num > 1 ){
            text.setError("Must be less than 1");
            num = -1.0;
            return num;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("answer:"+ num);
            return num;
            }
    }

    public void addRow(View v){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        EditText grade = new EditText(this);
        grade.setHint("0.0");
        grade.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        grade.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        grade.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        row.addView(grade);
        EditText weight = new EditText(this);
        weight.setHint("0.0");
        weight.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        weight.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        weight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        row.addView(weight);
        t1.addView(row);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add method that will retrieve current data from db and prepare views, then call it at the end of `onCreate()`.

Comment: The data was actually saving in the SQLite database. My problem was I was not repopulating the table. See my code below if you want to see how I repopulated my table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I repopulated my table: The SQLite database had saved my data but I was not placing it back into the table.

```
 public void populateTable(){
            //list of all the data from each row
            //each row is stored as an instance of the Entry class
            List<Entry> grab_all = populateList();
            for (int i = 0; i<(grab_all.size()-1); i++){
                addRow();       
            }

            int child_count = t1.getChildCount();
            //loops through each row
            for (int i=0; i<child_count; i++){
                TableRow row = (TableRow)t1.getChildAt(i);
                //loops through each column to input data from the table
                for (int m=0; m<row.getChildCount();m++){
                    EditText text = (EditText)row.getChildAt(m);

                    if (m == 0){//first textfield accepts letters
                        text.setText((grab_all.get(i).getDESCRIPT()));
                    }
                    else if (m==1){
                        text.setText(String.valueOf(grab_all.get(i).getGRADE()));
                    }
                    else
                        text.setText(String.valueOf(grab_all.get(i).getWEIGHT()));
                }
            }

        }
```